# Is it possible to rotate Google Maps into specific bearing?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing a simple app that has a generalized, drawed, map image, but I want to add the ability to switch between this map and the sattelite image of Google Maps. However I do want the Google Maps oriented in a specific bearing. Is this in any way possible?
Any other idea of solution?

Regards, Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonas,

I don't think the [Google Maps JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) supports arbitrary bearings. Google has a cache of rendered map tiles for the "normal" bearing, and I think rendering and caching tiles for other bearing points would be prohibitively expensive. Also, the mathematical algorithms would need to be updated to support that scenario.

However, Google Earth might do the trick. It's also possible you could render your own map tiles with something like [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/).

Good luck!